# Giant shoulders

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design, humans, anatomy

Many fictional characters,specially in the anime art have shoulders bigger than any other upper body muscle. Normally the obliques,chest and latissimus dorsi are the biggest muscles in the upper body but in anime the shoulders are actually bigger than the head.

[image]

These are the proportions I'm talking about,normally in humans the shoulders are merely assistance muscles which help the rest of the body on stabilizing the arms, but in anime the rest of the body is an assistance muscle to the shoulders.

Humans who somehow evolved shoulders this big would function differently than normal humans in basic activities or would they just be stronger and no other real difference would be noticed?

Comment: "if they were to develop through evolution" then nothing would *happen* to them, it would be just a way they are. Beneficial, if evolved.

Comment: What would happen in what aspect? Is there anything you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: In the very least warcraftian armor would a thing in the real world.

Comment: @Renan or warcraft would need even BIGGER shoulder pads!

Comment: "would they even be able to function properly" question is moot - given the requirement that it happened via evolution, they would function *better* than humans with normal shoulders, in the environment that pressured them to evolve big ones. That's evolution.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You're asking what would happen, but there's not really anything to say. Natural developments balance themselves out as is the evolutionary process. Is there a specific situation you're curious about? Is there a specific concern you have? All this would mean is these characters might actually be able to do the wrist and ankle weight training without as much risk to hurting themselves now, but I don't think that was what you meant.

Comment: Now *that's* irony! A question about broad shoulders get's flagged for being too broad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Shoulder dislocation would be less common, although reducing the dislocation would be much harder.
- If women do not evolve with larger hips and broader vaginal canal, there will be more deaths during labor, affecting both mother and child. That could result in more caesareans.
- More strength on the upper body, although if other muscles do not evolve similarly, there won't be much difference since you need muscle synergy.
- Less mobility since you won't have much range of motion of the upper limbs.
- Larger seats so you could sit comfortably not rubbing shoulder to the person next to you.
- Scratcher would be a well paid profession, since you can't reach your back. Ok that one is a joke, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

**Nothing Interesting**

If it's happening through evolution, then the selection underlying this muscle growth would also select for the best support mechanisms for it, ie more muscular backs, bigger abs, bigger bones in the back and shoulders. Modern bodybuilders get close to anime proportions with minor negative effects on their bodies, like reduced flexibility. Assuming that that the evolved humans increase the size of their shoulders to gigantic proportions through training, we can look to body building to get an idea of what might happen. 
Otherwise, the only noticable effect would be increased vertical lift strength when using the arms, since that's how the muscles in the shoulders are set up to work.